# MSBuild fail to build web site with reference a Bcl related library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web, msbuild, base-class-library

**I have 2 projects (.Net 4.0)**

- A class library (DataProvider)

  - Add reference to Bcl.Async library (via nuget)
  - Provide some async methods
- A web site (SampleSite)

  - Reference to "DataProvider"

**The problem:**

- When I build with Visual studio, everything is fine (I use VS 2017 Community)
- When try with MSBuild (MSBuild /target:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /m:4), I get this warning "..\WebSite1_1_.metaproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
  ..\WebSite1_1_.metaproj : warning MSB3268: The primary reference "...\WebSite1\DataProvider\bin\Debug\DataProvider.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly 
  "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". 
  To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "...\WebSite1\DataProvider\bin\Debug\DataProvider.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"."
- The latest DataProvider dll won't be copied to the Bin folder of "SampleSite", if I use some thing new from DataProvider I will get error (build fail)

**I have searched around, including StackOverFlow. But I can't find anything related to my scenario.**

**I tried:**

- Update app.config/web.config
- Copy BCL dlls to .Net 4.0 references assemblies folder
- Read through this (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb/) but can't find any way to solve my issue

(no code for this question)

**My expectation:**

- I can use MSBuild or something automatically to solve this problem (because this issue is happened on my build server, automatically)

**Update images**

- Solution [image: Solution structure]
- Just added new property to DataProvider: [image: Add new property]
- Use it normally on Website: [image: reference okay]
- MSBuild output: [image: output]
- DataProvider project: [image]

If I Right-Click on "WebSite2" -> Build web site, everything will be fine. But I want to use msbuild for automation job

Comment: This is a known issue for `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package, see [dotnet/cli 5993#](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5993). If your .net 4.0 project is SDK format, I think they are same issues.

Comment: In my case, there's only warning about the BCL.

The problem is only when I use MsBuild, it's okay with the visual studio, I can code, build, debug... etc

Comment: Actually, if you create a new simple class library in VS in same solution, and add reference to DataProvider project, you can get the warning even in VS.

Comment: Yes  but It's okay if "SampleSite" is a WebApplication.
In my case, it's a Web site, when adding reference to "DataProvider", it copies the DataProvider.dll to the Bin folder of "SampleSite".

If I build with VisualStudio, the DataProvider.dll is updated, and the new code of "DataProvider" used in "SampleSite" is okay.
If I use MSBuild it show warning, then show error when building "SampleSite" (it means the DataProvider.dll isn't updated)

Comment: What's the format of DataProvider's project file? new sdk format or old one?

Comment: I updated question with some images.There's also project file of DataProvider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197607/discussion-between-lance-li-msft-and-haiduong87).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now reproduce same issue in my machine(details see #4594), since it has some difference from [#5993](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5993), I report it in `msbuild` instead of `dotnet cli`. Issue reported to [Msbuild 4594](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4594).

And a workaround which can work in command-line is to use [devenv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) commands.

But it requires us to install **VS** in build machine, then we can use `devenv command` like:

[image]

Use the `-Rebuild` switch can works well like what it behaves in VS. See [Remark1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/rebuild-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019#remarks).

In my opinion, if we build this specific solution in vs, it may make more actions behind than single msbuild.exe does. And that's why it works well in vs but not msbuild command-line.

So if we need to **automatically** build this particular website in build server, we can try to use devenv command.(To see build output,it seems using `devenv.com` is better than using `devenv.exe`, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019#devenv-switch-syntax))

Hope it makes some help and let's track the issue in 4594.

Comment: This work around is fine with me, I can install vs on my build machine.
Thanks for asking it on github!